# Call KeyUp event

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited a rather in depth and complex excel workbook that I was tasked with adding onto.

The workbook is designed for the user to enter info into a textbox on the 1st sheet and pressing enter causes a keyup event to trigger.

I'm curious if there is a way to call that routine from a button event on another sheet??

```
Public Sub txtbx_length_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
         Case Asc(vbCr), Asc(vbLf), Asc(vbCrLf):
             Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
             process_length_val Me.txtbx_length.Value
             Me.txtbx_length.Value = ""
             Me.txtbx_length.Activate
             Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Case Asc("E"):     ' , Asc("e"):
        ' In tests, regardless if I had the shift key pressed or caps lock,
        ' or nothing, I always seen "E" come across -- never "e".  
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
            process_length_val Me.txtbx_length.Value
            Me.txtbx_length.Value = ""
            Me.txtbx_length.Activate
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End Select
```

I want to avoid send keys since its simply not reliable depending on what has focus. Especially with the enter key.

I've tried:

```
txtbx_length_KeyUp
```

and

```
call txtbx_length_KeyUp
```

but both give an error saying "sub or function not defined"

I'm curious if there is a way to call that routine from a button event on another sheet??

Comment: There's no difference between the two `Case` blocks there?  And why do you want to call a `KeyUp` event from a button, when there's no key involved?  What are you hoping to achieve here?

Comment: Also - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation  There is no constant `xlCalculateManual`

Comment: Don't invoke event handlers directly - they're there to _handle events_ and be invoked by the UI framework (and should always be `Private`). Instead, pull the logic you have there into its own procedure, and call that procedure from the event handler... and/or from anywhere else you like.

Comment: That said since you did make it `Public`, you can invoke it if you have a reference to an instance of the form: `thatInstance.txtbx_length_KeyUp 65, 0`, or `UserForm1.txtbx_length_KeyUp 65, 0` if you're showing the form's _default instance_ (note: that's somewhat dangerous /bug-prone, but kudos for referring to the current instance with the `Me` qualifier in the form's code-behind). With the optional/redundant `Call` keyword that would be `Call formInstance.txtbx_length_KeyUp(65, 0)`, to trigger a KeyUp event from a fake "a" keypress (without the Shift key).. still, very likely a bad idea.

Comment: Given the presence of a non-existent `xlCalculateManual` identifier here, I'd also warmly recommend adding `Option Explicit` at the top of all your modules, and addressing any compile-time errors it causes. Also consider having your code reviewed by [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) inspections, as it'll flag these kinds of things for you at design-time.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - the textbox is on a worksheet

Comment: Oh! Well, similar then: use the worksheet (vs form) instance as a qualifier - `SheetXyz.AnyPublicMethod`. Some reading would probably be recommended about using objects and invoking their methods in VBA.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon  I do not think it's so simple in this specific event case... `KeyCode` is not an `Integer` as it looks at the first glance. It is **an object** and it is **not so easy to `Set` it**. Then, it has only a property (`Value`) and it's easy to place there the key code. If you try `Public KeyC As MSForms.ReturnInteger` you need to `Set` it. If trying  `Public KeyC As New MSForms.ReturnInteger` it accepts declaration, but when you try `KeyC.Value = vbKeyReturn` it raises 'Class not registered' error message. It must be somehow intercepted from such a control...

Comment: @TimWilliams This is not my code. The rest of the code is very difficult for me to understand because of the way the previous programmer wrote it. My company obtained a digital measuring device to replace measuring by hand. The goal is to get the measurements from the tool and hand feed the input box that is normally hand typed from the manual measurements. The most logical way I have come up with is to get the length into the textbox and call the code that was already in place but don't want to use something like send keys , hence call the original sub

Comment: The textbox just feeds a value into `process_length_val`, so likely the best appraoch would be to call that directly with the value you want to pass in, and forget about the KeyUp part.

Comment: ...in short, it seems like you don't need the textbox at all here. What is involved in "get the measurements from the tool" though?

Comment: An ethernet connection to the tool, linked through the excel doc. As parts are sent through a machine, it measures the total length. I get a list like 1 25.13548631, 2 24.31813521 .......      The textbox is used to add the number of parts and their length. Which used to be hand measured and keyed in. With this tool I have the measurements input into 1 sheet and need to add them into the code sequence that is already in place. Its rather complex and handles transferring parts to different order #'s among other things.

Comment: The lettered solution by FaneDuru below works perfectly!

Comment: If you have a value (eg) "1 25.13548631" in A1 for example, then you only need to call `process_length_val ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value`  You can easily put that in a loop to process multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of seeing if/how it works, please try the next way:

1. `KeyCode` is not an `Integer`, as it may look. It is an object/class! Having a single (`value`) property which is passed by the keyboard. So, an event can be called from another `Sub` if you are able to use/create the necessary parameters. Please, copy the next declaration **on top of a standard module** (in the declarations area):

```
  Public KeyCodeObj As MSForms.ReturnInteger
```

2. Add a new line in the existing event code, as you have it:

```
Public Sub txtbx_length_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCodeObj Is Nothing Then Set KeyCodeObj = KeyCode 'the necessary line, to set the necessary objec (to be used when calling the event)
    Select Case KeyCode
         Case Asc(vbCr), Asc(vbLf), Asc(vbCrLf):
             Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
             process_length_val Me.txtbx_length.Value
             Me.txtbx_length.Value = ""
             Me.txtbx_length.Activate
             Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Case Asc("E"):     ' , Asc("e"):
        ' In tests, regardless if I had the shift key pressed or caps lock,
        ' or nothing, I always seen "E" come across -- never "e".  
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
            process_length_val Me.txtbx_length.Value
            Me.txtbx_length.Value = ""
            Me.txtbx_length.Activate
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     End Select
End Sub
```

3. Copy the next code able to call the above event, in any code module:

```
Private Sub callKeyUpEvent()
    Const sheetName As String = "Report" 'use here your sheet name where the text box in discussion exists
    Const directCallMask As Integer = 8 'direct-call functionality
    
    KeyCodeObj.Value = vbKeyReturn 'Enter. Or any other key code to be sent...
    Call Worksheets(sheetName).txtbx_length_KeyUp(KeyCodeObj, directCallMask)
End Sub
```

4. Now, **write anything in `txtbx_length` text box, or only press `Enter`**, in order to set the necessary `KeyCodeObj` object.
5. **Only after that**, run `callKeyUpEvent` procedure to call the event.

Note: Since `KeyCodeObj` variable is volatile (existing only in Excel memory), it may disappear in case of errors followed by code interruption. So, some ways of checking and re setting the object variable may be necessary. Even if it is not so simple, needing a real key press in the respective text box. Probably, such a simulation may be possible, but it does not make the object of the question, I would say :)

The above solution only means that doing what you want is possible (in that way), but it is not a **really reliable solution"! Especially, because of the difficulty to set the necessary object, otherwise than catching it from the event (at least, I do not know how it will be possible.).

A reliable solution, doin what you need **in a reliable way**, would be the next one:

A. Create a sub called with `KeyCode` converted as `Integer` which to be called by the event. Please, copy the next code in a **standard module**:

```
Sub DoTheJob(keyCode As Integer)
     Select Case keyCode
         Case vbKeyReturn
             MsgBox "Enter key has been pressed..."
             'place here your code to be triggered by that specific key (`Enter`)...
         Case vbKeyE
            MsgBox "E key has been pressed..."
            'place here your code to be triggered by that specific key (`E`)...
     End Select
End Sub
```

B. The existing event code will be modified in:

```
Public Sub txtbx_length_KeyUp(ByVal keyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCodeObj Is Nothing Then Set KeyCodeObj = keyCode 'only to offer the possibility to direcly call THE EVENT

    DoTheJob CInt(keyCode) 'cast the object to a simple Integer...
End Sub
```

3. Now, the above `DoTheJob` sub is called by the event, but **it can also  be called directly** (or from any other event, procedure etc.) as:

```
Sub testDoTheJob()
    DoTheJob vbKeyReturn
    DoTheJob vbKeyE
End Sub
```

Comment: I followed what you said but I get an error saying "Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set" on the line "KeyCodeObj.Value = vbKeyReturn". I did enter Public KeyCodeObj As MSForms.ReturnInteger into a module, I'm not sure why that wouldn't be set?

Comment: @SamwiseVB Please, pay more attention to the issues 1, 4 and 5: 1. Did you declare the `Public` variable in a **standard module** (not in a sheet module)? 4. Did you do what Is recommended there, **to `Set` the object in discussion**? 5. Did you try the call only after setting the object, **as explained**? If you correctly did all that and still does not work, do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? I would like to see what's happening in your installation, if possible and you accept a connection...

Comment: @SamwiseVB Didn't you make it working? I am curious and I took it as a challenge... I do not need such a procedure, but I just wanted to prove that it works and I would like you saying that it worked in your case, too. Besides that, I edited my answer and placed a reliable solution, able to solve your problem in a reliable way. I would like to receive some feedback after testing it. For you, this second part should be more important, but I also need the confirmation that calling the event is possible in your case, too...

Comment: 1. I did declare. 4. I have had 8, 9, and 97 returned, keycode is 13. 5. Changed my sheet name and get an error "Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set" on the line "KeyCodeObj.Value = vbKeyReturn" This solution does not work for me.

I did implement the Lettered solution and that works like a charm! thank you for your time and help

Comment: @SamwiseVB I am sure that "this solution" works for you, if you exactly followed the steps as I tried explaining above... Did you **before testing it, activate the text box in discussion, click in its box and press a key (any key) then exit**? Only after that `KeyCodeObj` will be set... Do you have `TeamViewer` or `AnyDesk` applications installed? If so, I would like to show you what is to be done, if allow a connection. Just for the sake of demonstration...

Comment: @SamwiseVB Since our Time looks to not be compatible, sharing a dummy workbook with the way you tried implemented the above solution (calling the event) will also help. I will correct it and send it back explaining what you have to do... Try using [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site. It is free and easy to be used...